# How do disable a system tray icon's context menu in SWT?

Tags: java, menu, swt, contextmenu, system-tray

I have tray icon and I've attached a menu to it so that when the user right clicks on it, it pops up.

At point in my application I'd like to disable the content menu from showing and the re-enable it again later. How I do this? I haven't been able to find an example and doing `mnuPopup.setEnabled(false)` doesn't seem to work.

Here's the snippet of code that creates the tray icon and attaches the menu to it.

```
Tray trySysTray = display.getSystemTray();
Menu mnuPopup = new Menu(shell, SWT.POP_UP);
TrayItem itmTrayItem = new TrayItem(trySysTray, SWT.NONE);

itmTrayItem.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        mnuPopup.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```
public class MiniExample {
    // the boolean to decide if menu is shown
    private static boolean showMenu = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        Tray tray = display.getSystemTray();
        final TrayItem item = new TrayItem(tray, SWT.NONE);

        // INPUT A REAL IMAGE HERE!
        item.setImage(SOME_IMAGE);

        item.addMenuDetectListener(new MenuDetectListener() {

            @Override
            public void menuDetected(MenuDetectEvent event) {
            // if menu shall not be shown, tell it to the event
                if(!showMenu)
                {
                    event.doit = false;
                    return;
                }

            // else create the menu
                Menu menu = new Menu(shell, SWT.POP_UP);
                MenuItem menuitem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
                menuitem.setText("Do Something");
                menuitem.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
                    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                        System.out.println("Do something!");
                    }
                });

                menu.setVisible(true);
                while (!menu.isDisposed() && menu.isVisible()) {
                    if (!shell.getDisplay().readAndDispatch())
                        shell.getDisplay().sleep();
                }

            // remember to dispose it !!
                menu.dispose();
            }
        });

        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Button");
        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                // button decides if menu is shown or not
                showMenu = !showMenu;
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```